# How can I pass WM_KEYDOWN messages to the WinForms control inside CWinFormsView?

Tags: winforms, onkeydown

I have a WinForms control (let's say **C**) inside the CWinFormsView **V** of an MDI application. **C** overrides the *OnKeyDown* method. I have overriden also *OnMouseUp* in **C** and I call the *Focus()* method there, so when I click inside **C** the keyboard messages go directly to it and everything works correctly.

However, I'd like to be able to control **C** using the keyboard when I switch to **V** without the need to click inside the view. How can I achieve that? Do I need to catch WM_KEYDOWN messages in **V** and pass them manually to the hosted control (in other words, **C**)? **C** is actually a child window of **V**, shouldn't it somehow work automatically?

Comment: Override the view's OnInitDialog() method.  Case the base implementation, set the focus to one of the controls and return FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem with the following code in the **V** view:

```
BOOL CMyView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if( pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN || pMsg->message == WM_MOUSEWHEEL )
    {
        ::SendMessage( (HWND) m_myControl->Handle.ToInt32(), pMsg->message, pMsg->wParam, pMsg->lParam );
    }

    return CWinFormsView::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Also I removed the code that sets focus to **C** on mouse click. This way it is never focused but receives the parent view's messages (I need WM_KEYDOWN and WM_MOUSEWHEEL) from *PreTranslateMessage*. Not settings the focus is important because otherwise I would lose the ability to switch between MDI views using Ctrl+Tab (if **C** was focused). So now I can switch between them freely, then when **V** becomes active I can use the keys to control **C** but I still can use Ctrl+Tab to switch to another view without having to use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed your question, the easiest way is to have V forward the presses to C.

Look at `Form.KeyPreview` - for V - which will let V see all the key presses when it or one of it's children have focus.  You can then forward it to C.